# Error: Unexpected request: GET layouts/index.html - AngularJS unit test - Karma

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, httpbackend

I get that error since my `app.config` file is included in my tests. It makes all my unit tests involving httpbackend fail. They usually look like this:

```
beforeEach(function(){
  module('consumerApp');
  inject(function($injector) {
    httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
  });
});

describe('foo', function(){
  it('does something', inject(function(Foo){
    httpBackend.when("POST", URL).respond(json);

    Foo.something();
    httpBackend.flush();
    expect(Foo.stuff).toEqual('done');
  }));
});
```

I am not sure why the unit tests need to call my templates to run...

Comment: How does your app.config look like?

Comment: You have to find where does this GET request come from, and if this is an intended behavior (dynamic loading) handle it in your tests by setting `httpBackend.expectGET('layouts/index.html');` (before the action) and `httpBackend.flush();` (after the action)

Comment: Did you found a solution for your problem?

Comment: No I removed the config.js file from my unit test files for now.